# jar: command not found in Bash

Tags: java, jar, environment-variables

I created one jar file in following location: **'/usr/local/bin/niidle.jar'**

But when I type command as follows:

```
jar tf /usr/local/bin/niidle.jar
```

then it shows the following error:

```
--The program 'jar' can be found in the following packages:
 * java-gcj-compat-headless
 * gcj-4.2
 * sun-java5-jdk
 * kaffe
 * gcj-4.3
 * cacao-oj6-jdk
 * openjdk-6-jdk
 * fastjar
 * sun-java6-jdk
Try: apt-get install <selected package>
bash: jar: command not found
```

Do you have a solution for this?

Comment: This is more a Linux question than a Java question...

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the `jar` program is not found by the operating system. Have you installed any of the packages containing it, and set up your path correctly?

In order for the OS to find an executable, the `path` environment variable must include the directory where that program is located. Otherwise you need to specify its full path to access it.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it can't find the `jar` program. Perhaps your JDK isn't on the path, or you haven't installed one? If you *have* installed one, try to find where it is, and look in there for the `jar` program.

Answer (score 1):

Try runnning "java -jar /usr/local/bin/niidle.jar"

Answer (score 1):

On Ubuntu 12.10 The program jar is in /usr/lib/jvm/jdk-[version]/bin
edit the file /etc/environment for add to the path. Close the session and open a new session.

Answer (score 0):

You seems to be using either Debian or Ubuntu. And it is telling you that you did not install one of the packages containing the 'jar' executable. You will have to install one corresponding to the java package you use on your system. In order to know which java package you already have type this : dpkg -l | grep java

Answer (score 0):

If you are like me and you already have everything installed, but you just get the same error when trying to type `jar`: it should be listed in your `PATH`.

1. Run `echo $PATH`.
2. If you're like me, it does not contain the entry like this `/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_66/bin`.
3. Make sure it's not `$JAVA_HOME/bin`, all variables should be expanded!
4. If you don't have the entry, but have `JAVA_HOME` set, run `export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin`
5. See if you got the `jar` command.
6. If it does, google about environment variables to set that effect forever.
7. Have a nice day.