# Ubuntu 14.04,unable to package classes into 'jar' file

Tags: java, oracle, ubuntu, jar, manifest

I am learing Java from'HeadFirst Java' 
My current setup is Ubuntu 14.04

Oracle JDK 1.8 is installed and set as defaut
,Oracle Java is also set as default

I have Many Tools such as AndroidStudio and Eclipse Perfectly working and dont want to break them,by changing to Open JDK

**My Problem is**

I am tyring an exercise on Java Packaging and Deployement

Directory Structure 
:MYProject:->Classes,Source

Source:->MyBall.Java
Classes:MyPanel.class,MyBall.class etc,manifest.text(contains Min-Class:MyBall)

With Present Working Directory as 'MyProject' I want to make the Source Folder as a JAR

The Book says :

```
jar -cvmf manifest.txt app1 .jar *.class
```

should do the trick

But the output i get is

```
The program 'jar' can be found in the following packages:

 * default-jdk
 * fastjar
 * gcj-4.8-jdk
 * openjdk-7-jdk
 * gcj-4.6-jdk
 * openjdk-6-jdk
```

Here are the versions:

```
java version "1.8.0_11"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_11-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.11-b03, mixed mode)

javac 1.8.0_11
```

I find this to be relevant https://stackoverflow.com/a/18166639/3725998
But dont know how to change variable etc , Not a Linux Expert , So Please Guide me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need to do is tell the operating system where the jar program lives.  In your home directory, you will most likely have a file called `.bashrc`.  Go to the end of the file and add the following:

```
export JAVA_HOME=<path to your JDK install e.g. /opt/jdk>
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

This sets your JAVA_HOME environment variable - commonly used by Java-based applications such as Tomcat.  It then prepends that directory to your PATH variable.  The operating system understands PATH as a list of the parent directories of executable files.

When you have changed your file, type the following at the command prompt to re-load your shell profile:

```
. .bashrc
```

Comment: No use , still the same ,The program 'jar' can be found in the following packages:

 * default-jdk
 * fastjar
 * gcj-4.8-jdk
 * openjdk-7-jdk
 * gcj-4.6-jdk
 * openjdk-6-jdk

Comment: Hmmm...what happens when you type 'which jar' at the command prompt?

Comment: Ops Sorry , Didnt Restart the session , now 'which jar' shows the installed Jdk Directory , do I need to worry about any other installed tools such as Eclipse breaking due to this addition in PATH?

Comment: My fault as much as yours - I should have pointed out you need to type . .bashrc to reload the shell profile after making the change (have edited the post to reflect this).  In regards to your question of breaking things - no, it will not hurt Eclipse or anything else.

Answer (score 1):

In Ubuntu 14.04 edit /etc/environment to add the JAVA_HOME

```
sudo gedit /etc/environment
```

Add the line

```
JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-[version]"
```

Reload the file

```
source /etc/environment
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, there should not be an space between `app1` and `.jar`. So, if Java is installed correctly, this should do the trick.

```
jar -cvmf manifest.txt app1.jar *.class
```

However, I don't think that's the cause of your error.

You can try updating to the latest version of Oracle Java 8. I find this guide easy to follow, even if you don't have a lot of experience with Linux.

http://www.webupd8.org/2012/09/install-oracle-java-8-in-ubuntu-via-ppa.html

Comment: Checked its already at the latest version, please look at the link i pasted and tell me how to edit the environment variable ,add path etc without breaking anything